# using linebreaks in minted environment without newline character

Tags: minted

I'm using Doxygen to generate LaTeX code from source,
and want to use the minted package for code highlighting from comments.
I'm using the doxygen `f{minted{{java} ... \}` command section,
which properly generates
`\begin{minted}{java} \end{minted}`,
but all my newlines from the doxygen document are removed and I can't force doxygen to keep them as far as I know.

Is there any way to force minted to consider a command a newline and use code formatting properly?

Example:

```
/**
 * \f{minted}{{java}
 * code; // comment
 * other code; // here it all goes terribly wrong without linebreaks
 * 
 * more code; 
 * \}
 */
```

Comment: it would be easier to answer without requiring doxygen if you posted a complete small latex document with the dropped line endings for testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fancyvrb` requires a newline on the lines with `\begin{minted}` and `\end{minted}` but you can replace all the newlines in the code by an otherwise unused character I use `` ` `` here.

The first display has normal line breaks, the second is all on one line.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}



AAA
\begin{minted}{C}
if(!foo){
 for(zz=0;zz<-1;zz++) {
    a=b;
 }
}
\end{minted}

BBB
{\newlinechar=`\`
\begin{minted}{C}
if(!foo){` for(ww=0;ww<-1;ww++) {`    x=y;` }`}
\end{minted}
}


\end{document}
```